# Simplifying if, else-if, else with Java optional

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, refactoring, option-type

I have a method which takes in 3 parameters, all of which are optional. Implementation of the method is as follows.

```
public static Person getPerson(Optional<String> id, Optional<List> jobs, Optional<String> country) {
    Person p = null;
 
    if(id.isPresent() && jobs.isPresent()) {
      p = Person.builder.withName("Name").withId(id.get()).withJobs(jobs.get()).build();
    } else if (id.isPresent()) {
       p = Person.builder.withName("Name").withId(id.get()).build();
    } else {
       p = Person.builder.withName("Name").build();
    }
    return p;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this with Optional.map.orElseGet pattern? If its just the id I could think of a way, but since jobs is also optional I'm not sure how I could use that. Any advice to refactor this code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes.. Create builder then if something extists the add to builder `var b = Person.builder.withName("Name")` if(id.isPresent()) b.withId(..);

Comment: You can use`orElse` like `Person.builder.withName("Name").withId(id.orElse(null))....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a builder object and use `ifPresent` and assign the corresponding fields.

```
PersonBuilder builder = Person.builder.withName("Name");

id.ifPresent(idValue -> builder.withId(idValue));
jobs.ifPresent(jobsValue -> builder.withJobs(jobsValue));

return builder.build();
```

As Michael suggests, you can also replace the lambda expression with a method reference (`builder::withId`, `builder::withJobs`).

Comment: `id.ifPresent(builder::withId);`